# How to display images and .css file in .jsp

Tags: jsp, contextpath

I have a file FixHome.jsp that is trying to display a logo and formatting from style.css. However, when I run the .jsp file the image does not appear and the formatting from the stye.css file is not implemented.

The file locations are under the FixConnections project as follows:

/WebContent/FixHome.jsp

/WebContent/Resources/style.css

/WebContent/Resources/needhamlogo2.bmp

I'm using Eclipse and running Tomcat 7.0

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Resources/style.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Fix Connections</title>
</head>
<body>
<table bgcolor="black" id="shell" height="100%" width="100%">
 <tr height="30">
  <td bgcolor="white">
     <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Resources/NeedhamLogo2.bmp"/> 
  </td>
  <td bgcolor="white"> 
    FIX Connections 
  </td> 
</tr> 
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know if I am references the image and .css file correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use relative hrefs:

```
href="Resources/style.css"
```

Alternativly, add a leading slash. contextPath returns just a String, so your href renders something like:

```
href="ctxt/Resources/style.css"
```

While you need one of:

```
href="/ctxt/Resources/style.css"
href="Resources/style.css"
```

Comment: I tried `href="Resources/style.css"` however it still isn't taking effect on the page. Could there be another issue?

Comment: Can't you check what is being rendered in your html, just look at the html source. After that check if the rendered URL can be accessed.

Comment: It works now. Seems I had to restart eclipse for it to take effect. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try using default servlet see doc 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/default-servlet.html

in jsp( example)

```
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

in web.xml( example)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```